# Trouble figuring out why my procedure to print out bits of each integer in an array isn't working

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a class that optimizes an array of booleans by storing an ordered array of integers whose bits individual bits can be accessed to see if they're on or off. Yes, I know that

```
std::vector<bool>
```

does something like this, but I'm trying to make my own implementation, for practice.

For instance, an unsigned short int is 16 bits, so I can pack 100 bools into an array of of 7 unsigned short ints where the last element acts as padding.

As I test this, I see that something is already going wrong, possibly something with my print() function. In main you can see that I made a BitPack object of 32 bools, which will be stored in an array of 2 unsigned short ints, and I've verified that this is so. However, my print function isn't working because it gives me the following output, which isn't 32 zeros, as it should be.

```
0000000000000000
```

I've looked over my print function numerous times and can't figure out what is wrong. Sorry about any indentations that got lost when I copied my code here. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef unsigned short int usi;

class BitPack { 

public: 
    BitPack(int);
    ~BitPack(); 
    bool getVal(int);
    int getSize();
    void setVal(int, bool);
    void print();

private:
    const static int USI_BITS = sizeof(usi)*CHAR_BIT; 
    usi* _booArr;
    int _booArrLen;
    int _numBoos;

};

BitPack::BitPack(int sz) { 
     assert (sz > 0);           
      _numBoos = sz;
  _booArrLen = _numBoos/USI_BITS+(_numBoos % USI_BITS ? 1 : 0);
  _booArr = new usi[_booArrLen];
  for (int i = 0; i < _booArrLen; ++i)
     _booArr[i] = 0;
} 

BitPack::~BitPack() {
    delete[] _booArr;
}

bool BitPack::getVal(int indx) {
    assert (indx > 0);  
    usi bA_indx_val = _booArr[indx/USI_BITS];
    bA_indx_val >>= (bA_indx_val % USI_BITS);
    return (bA_indx_val % 2 ? true : false);
}

int BitPack::getSize() { 
    return (_numBoos);
}

void BitPack::setVal(int indx, bool valset) { 
    assert (indx > 0);
    bool curval = getVal(indx);
    if ((curval == true) && (valset == false)) {
        _booArr[indx/USI_BITS] += (1 << (indx % USI_BITS));
    } else if ((curval == true) && (valset == false)) {
        _booArr[indx/USI_BITS] -= (1 << (indx % USI_BITS));
    }
} 

void BitPack::print() { 
    int i = 0;
    usi thisval;
    while (i < _booArrLen - 1) {
        thisval = _booArr[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < USI_BITS; ++j) {
            std::cout << (thisval % 2 ? '1' : '0');
            thisval >>= 1;
        }
        i++;
    }
    thisval = _booArr[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < _numBoos % USI_BITS; ++j) { 
        std::cout << (thisval % 2 ? '1' : '0');
        thisval >>= 1;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char* const argv[]) {

    BitPack bp(32);
    bp.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing the values `_booArrLen` or `USI_BITS`?  That should indicate pretty quickly why you're seeing an unexpected number of `0`s print.

Comment: Did you know vector<bool> is already optimized for space? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool/  There is also std::bitset.

Comment: I mentioned in my original post that I know about vector<bool>. The reason I don't like std::bitset is because it's length must be a compiler-time constant.

Comment: My mistake.  I totally overlooked that!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors I found and corrected:

```
bool BitPack::getVal(int indx) {
    assert (indx >= 0);                 // Use >=
    usi bA_indx_val = _booArr[indx/USI_BITS];
    bA_indx_val >>= (indx % USI_BITS);  // use indx here instead of bA_indx_val
    return ((bA_indx_val & 1) ? true : false);
}
```

BitPack::setVal() also had some problems:

```
void BitPack::setVal(int indx, bool valset) {
    assert (indx >= 0);           // Use >= 
    bool curval = getVal(indx);
    if ((curval == true) && (valset == false)) {
        _booArr[indx/USI_BITS] &= ~(1 << (indx % USI_BITS));  // Use bitwise operators
    } else if ((curval == false) && (valset == true)) {       // corrected this expression
        _booArr[indx/USI_BITS] |= (1 << (indx % USI_BITS));   // Use bitwise operators
    }
}
```

Using -= and += to manipulate bits is a lot more difficult to get right than &= and |= bitwise operators.

It seems to work with a few basic tests, but I didn't verify if it works for all bit positions.

Comment: I'm not skilled at using the bitshift operators like you guys are!!!!!!!! I hope to someday use them like basic arithmetic.

Comment: Keep practicing like you are and soon enough, it will be a piece of cake.

Answer (score 0):

'This can be done in VB.NET.

'I have an array of 20 Shorts or Integers and I want to transfer these both into and out of a Boolean Array of 320 Items (16 bits)

'I'm using a checkbox array but can us Treeview or other Boolean Object Array

'MyCheckbox(320) is declared as Public

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub ReadData() 'Reads Integer (0-65535)

```
Dim Intx As Int16
Dim Bit As Int16
 
For Intx = 0 To 19
        For Bit = 0 To 15
            MyCheckbox(Bit + (Intx * 16)).Checked = CBool(MyDataTable.Data(Intx) And CInt(2 ^ Bit))
        Next Bit
    Next Intx
End Sub
```

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Private Sub WriteData() ' Writes same data back as Short if it has changed (-32768-32767)

Dim Shorty As Short
Dim Bit As Short

```
For Shorty = 0 To 19 ' Array of 20 Type Integer or Short
     For Bit = 0 To 15 ' 16 Bits
            If MyCheckbox(Bit + (Shorty * 16)).Checked Then
                MyDataTable.Data(Shorty) = (MyDataTable.Data(Shorty) Or CShort(1S << Bit))
                Else
                  MyDataTable.Data(Shorty) = (MyDataTable.Data(Shorty) And Not (CShort(1S << Bit)))
             End If           
Next
    Next
End Sub
```

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------